# Join documents in a collection that share same value in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

How do I merge two documents in a collection that share same value - Cycle?

```
{'Time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 25, 9, 4, 39),
 'Cycle': 3796,
 'Explanation': 'A 00146 - Q plastification time',
 '_id': ObjectId('5976272b4a20d138cce55aa3')}
```

and

```
{'A [s]': 0.0,
 'B [s]': 0.81,
 'C [s]': 3.0,
 'Time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 10, 33, 10),
 'PauseTime Z [s]': 0.01,
 'Cycle': 3796,
 '_id': ObjectId('597627244a20d138cce5197a')}
```

So that it would look like:

```
{'Time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 25, 9, 4, 39),
 'Cycle': 3796,
 'Explanation': 'A 00146 - Q plastification time',
 'A [s]': 0.0,
 'B [s]': 0.81,
 'C [s]': 3.0,
 'Time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 10, 33, 10),
 'PauseTime Z [s]': 0.01,
 '_id': ObjectId('_______')}
```

Comment: That example is not possible as a document is handled as a dictionary and a dictionary can't map one single key to two different values (e.g. Time, which is probably the same assumption as in the mongoDB core and not only in python's interface pymongo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first document you show is in a collection called "c1" and the second is in a collection called "c2", you can join them using the MongoDB aggregation operator, "$lookup":

```
for doc in db.c2.aggregate([{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'c1',
        'localField': 'Cycle',
        'foreignField': 'Cycle',
        'as': 'joined'
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'Time1': '$Time',
        'Cycle': '$Cycle',
        'Explanation': '$joined.Explanation',
        'Time2': '$joined.Time',
        'A [s]': '$A [s]',
        'B [s]': '$B [s]',
        'C [s]': '$C [s]',
        'PauseTime Z [s]': '$PauseTime Z [s]'

    }
}]):
    pprint.pprint(doc)
```

This outputs:

```
{u'A [s]': 0.0,
 u'B [s]': 0.81,
 u'C [s]': 3.0,
 u'Cycle': 3796,
 u'Explanation': [u'A 00146 - Q plastification time'],
 u'PauseTime Z [s]': 0.01,
 u'Time1': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 10, 33, 10),
 u'Time2': [datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 25, 9, 4, 39)],
 u'_id': ObjectId('597627244a20d138cce5197a')}
```

A dict can't have two keys with the same name, and a BSON document *shouldn't* have two keys with the same name, so I've renamed the two "Time" fields "Time1" and "Time2" in the "$project" phase.